# Variable inside a string inside array

Tags: php, string

i just looking for somthing like this:

```
<?php
$json = get_post_meta($post->ID, "json", $single = true);
$book = json_decode($json);
$genre = $book->genres
$cat_ids = array($genres);
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), $cat_ids, 'category' );
```

why it doesnt work?
how can i run this script:

```
$cat_ids = array($genres);
```

thanks for the answer

Comment: Missing `;` after `$genre = $book->genres` perhaps?

Comment: Fix the **;** like @MarkBaker said and beware of this line: 
$cat_ids = array($genres);  it should be $cat_ids = array(**$genre**);